# apex rest outbound class for rest inbound class

Tags: apex

I am trying to write the apex rest outbound program for below apex inbound rest service. 
Can you please help me on writing the outbound apex rest service. Thanks..

Apex rest outbound:

```
            //find access token using Auth 2.0 
            String Access_Token='access token';

            Httprequest req=new httprequest();
            String domainName= '<domainName>';
            String endPointURL='https://domainName-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/RestServiceContactCreation/';
            req.setendpoint(endPointURL);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
            req.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><request><name>'+contactLastName+'</name></request>');
            req.setmethod('POST');

            req.setHeader('Authorization','Authorization: Bearer '+Access_Token);
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            response=res.getbody();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is going wrong? The authentication?

Comment: It's not authentication. I would like to know how to pass contactLastName in req.setBody() in above apex program. Problem with the body - req.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><request><name>'+contactLastName+'</name></request>');

Answer (score 1):

Note that its best to build the request body using the [DOM Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) because they will take care of any necessary escaping. The code can also end up cleaner too.

I'm guessing here, but based on what happens for the JSON case (where the field names are used), the XML you need to send is probably either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<req><contactLastName>Smith</contactLastName></req>
```

or:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<contactLastName>Smith</contactLastName>
```

*PS*

In response to your comment you need the controller referenced by the page to have a public property and reference that in your method:

```
public with sharing ContactCreationRestservice_Outbound {

    public String contactLastName {get; set;}

    public PageReference CreateContact() {
        ...
        req.setBody('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><request><name>'+contactLastName+'</name></request>');
        ...
    }
}
```

See e.g. Trailhead's [Create & Use Custom Controllers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_custom_controllers).

Comment: Keith, I want to pass the contact last name from visualforce page. I have updated visualforce page in above question. I don't want to send static data. I want to send data dynamically from visual force page.

Comment: why dont you ask the real question in your question instead of making us all guess what you want??